# Delay of Javascript based Tumblr width calculation

Tags: javascript, css, tumblr

my Tumblr theme CSS width is changed by javascript code (according to the number of posts).

Theme is loaded with the standard width and after the number of posts is known, the new width is calculated by the following javascript function (to fit posts).

PROBLEM is the big delay of this calculation (it waits until content of posts is loaded)!

Is it possible to calculate and set width immediately based on number of posts and not to wait for posts content loading?

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function resizedivs() {

$ = function(id) { return document.getElementById(id); }

fschildren = $("fs_wrapper").childNodes;
postc = 0;
thedivs = new Array();

for(i = 0; i < fschildren.length; i++) {
    if(fschildren[i].tagName == "DIV") {
        thedivs[postc] = fschildren[i];
        postc++;
    }
}

newwidth = 0;
for(i = 0; i < thedivs.length; i++) {
    if(newwidth <= document.body.clientWidth) {
        newwidth = newwidth + (thedivs[i].clientWidth)+15;
    }

    if(newwidth >= document.body.clientWidth || newwidth >= 1300) { // 100 for padding minus 15 extra
        newwidth = newwidth - (thedivs[i].clientWidth+15);
        break;
    }
}

$("fs_wrapper").style.width = newwidth-0+"px";
$("fs_wrapper").style.position = "relative";
$("fs_wrapper").style.left = "0px";

$("sec2").style.width = newwidth-0+"px";
$("sec2").style.position = "relative";
$("sec2").style.left = "0px";

$("sec3").style.width = newwidth-0+"px";
$("sec3").style.position = "relative";
$("sec3").style.left = "0px";

}

window.onresize = function() {
    resizedivs();

}

window.onload = function() {
    resizedivs();
}
</script>
```

Comment: Why don't you make your theme responsive?

Comment: How does tumblr load? If you have the number of posts at page init time, e.g. it's written into the page HTML, you can probably do this onLoad. Else you might need to hook into the Tumblr code so that you have the post count the instant it does from its APIs.

Comment: TO P1nGu1n: What do you mean by responsive theme?

Comment: TO Rup: It seems to me, that the number of posts is known at page init time. See example at http://test.trena.de

Comment: Your script is asking to wait for all content in the window to be loaded before calling the function: `window.onload`. Ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers.onload